# Storing data on the google app engine with python trouble

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am attempting to store data via python on the datastore.. but i am not succeeding.

I have looked at the documentation but still cannot manage to get my app working.

I have the following code which should define some data. put it to the appspot domain. and some django which should display the data(but uncertain as how to do this).

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
# A Model for a User
class Pokemondata(db.Model):
name = db.StringProperty()
pokemon= User(name="balbasaur")
pokemon.put()

class ApplyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
   pname = self.request.get('name')

   pokemon= User(name=pname,acct=xacct,pw=xpw);
   pokemon.put();
   self.session['pokemon'] = pname

  def get(self):
   que = db.Query(Pokemondata)

   poke_list = que.fetch(limit=5)

   Page = """
    <html manifest="my.manifest">

    <body>

       <h1>%s's App Engine App</h>

    </body>
    </html>
    """     

   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', User),
                                         ('/json', ApplyHandler)], debug=True)
  def Addlist():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

   if __name__ == "__Addlist__":
    main()
```

I am unsure as how to display the data. Any advice would be appreicated

Thanks

J

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And your program structure appears to be nonsense: why have you got the application object defined inside a method, and why are you calling run_wsgi_app? And why, if you've defined a Pokemondata model, are you instantiating and saving a User?

Comment: you get method doesn't really do anything.  You should be using self.response.write() to in addition you have define Page as a string, but you aren't doing anything with it.  I would go back to the basic tutorials and work through them first.

Answer (score 0):

I can try and help but fist just get something really simple working, like:

file -> main.py
The white space on the left is very important in python (or tabs)

```
import webapp2
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                          debug=True)
```

and the app.yaml file:
Both file must live in the same directory!

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
 - url: /.*
 script: main.app
```

Then in the same directory you start dev_appserver.py .

[Here is the link I am copying from](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/)

Go through the tutorial, don't get impatient and you will get going very soon
You will progress to templates, static files and data models

Comment: hi i appreciate your replies.

Comment: What i am doing is a uni project. The code was edited from my lectures example code which i am really intensely trying to understand. (we have never done python before at this level)

Comment: the indentation fixes when i laod it in wings IDE so it must be an error in the indent for this site

Comment: Go through the tutorial and then you should be able to complete your assignment

Comment: Thanks! doing just that right now. I have the hello world working.